# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty }(nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n)=0$

Tags: limits

I just tried to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}=\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}$.

First I let $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x^i$ so that $\lim_{n\to \infty}f'(x)=LHS$.

It's obvious that $f(x)=\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}$, therefore, $f'(x)=\frac{1+nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n}{(x-1)^2}$.

In order to prove $\lim_{n\to \infty}f'(x)=RHS$ we should have $\lim_{n \to \infty }(nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n)=0$. But I don't know how to derive it. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: For all $x\in{\Bbb R}$?. You can't. But for $|x|<1$ is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $|x|<1$ you have a common geometric series:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \frac{1}{1-x}.
$$
Since the convergence is uniform you can bring the derivative operator under the series operator, getting therefore:
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = \sum_{i=1}^\infty ix^{i-1} = \frac{1}{(x-1)^2}.
$$